# How to change location on disk of Windows XP Desktop files?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

It's easy to change the My Documents folder location, but what about the Desktop?  Is is possible to move it from the default location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Tweak UI powertoy](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx) from Microsoft supports setting the folder location (along with some of the other special folders)